# ui-router angular js does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular-ui-router

I am new in angularjs and I was creating new app,and when tried to use ui-router I failed I don't no why it's not working. Actually my error is this when I use ui-view to render some partial(transaction.html) it's not working and ui-sref shows error

```
Could not resolve 'transactions' from state ''
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3179)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3107)
    at angular-ui-router.js:4143
    at angular.js:19612
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5964)
    at angular.js:6243
```

I am using yeoman gulp and bower

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="web">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>anything</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
  <body>

 <!-- src/index.html -->
 <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-2" ng-controller="NavigationCtrl as navigation_ctrl">
        <h2>Деньги</h2>
        <h3 class="money-ok">
          {{navigation_ctrl.transactions_store.sum()}}
        </h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li>
             <a ui-sref="transactions">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
            Транзакции <span class="badge">{{navigation_ctrl.transctions_store.transactions.length}}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="settings">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i> Настройки
          </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" ui-view></div>
    </div>
```

index.js where I'm showing my routes

```
'use strict';

angular.module('web', ['restangular', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('transactions', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "app/main/transactions.html"
    })
    .state('settings', {
      url: "/settings",
      templateUrl: "app/settings/settings.html"
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
;
```

-----Added-----
if it helps

[my files in src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf8xm.png)

[files which loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGqIp.png)

Comment: Drop a `debugger;` statement on the line above $stateProvider make sure that gets triggered (debug panel open and refresh) seems like it just isn't loading that file for some reason also double check in the network tab in chrome tools as well (f12 or right click and inspect then click the network tab, filter for files you expect to have loaded like angular.js and your index.js make sure they loaded and the response for the request is the body you expect).  Also any other console errors before this one?

Comment: @shaunhusain I don't now why but it is not loads my transaction.html

Comment: still not working?

Comment: @Miqe yes, it is not loading my files and folders which I created for my self

Answer (score 0):

M̶y̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶g̶u̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶:̶ ̶<̶a̶ ̶u̶i̶-̶s̶r̶e̶f̶=̶"̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶"̶>̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶o̶r̶m̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶<̶a̶ ̶u̶i̶-̶s̶r̶e̶f̶=̶"̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶"̶ ̶h̶r̶e̶f̶=̶"̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶"̶>̶ ̶ ̶-̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶-̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶a̶t̶h̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶/̶.̶ ̶ ̶E̶i̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶d̶ ̶p̶a̶t̶h̶,̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶u̶i̶-̶s̶r̶e̶f̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶.̶

Edit:

After testing it does indeed transform to the correct URL. As agreed with the comment above, it can be cause by the `.html` templates that are not found/correct path.

Comment: I believe `<a ui-sref="transactions">` will change to `<a ui-sref="transactions" href="/">`

Comment: Absolutely correct @csschapker - thanks for making me test it.

Comment: Yep it's not loads my files